# Git delete submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have got a shared project with a number of submodules. Usually, when I want to update my working branch I execute next commands:

```
> git pull origin my_branch_name
```

and after that update my submodules:

```
> git submodule update --init --recursive
```

it updates all my submodules and initializes new one, if someone adds them to the project.

Problem is the project has got a lot of submodules, and some of them I don't use at all, but they require a lot of space on HDD. Is it possible to delete locally unused submodules and forbid git downloads them, when I update all submodules together?

Comment: Check this thread and its answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-submodule

Answer (score 1):

Don't delete them, just don't bother fetching them. That's part of the value of submodules, you don't have to fetch or check out anything you don't need.

`git submodule update --init --recursive` is the the command to fetch every submodule in sight and then repeat until no more can be found. That's not what you want, so don't do it.

Make a list of what needs doing and record that in a script. That's what scripts are for, to record common command sequences.  `history|awk '$2~/git|cd/'` can be useful, do whatever exploration you need and then hunt through your history to collect your paydirt.  You want to end up with a sequence of cd's and git submodule updates that does what you want, you'd have to make that list anyway, might as well keep it in a form the shell can use to redo it on command.